# Smoother Movement

Tags: java, movement

I have an object in my game that moves pretty slow, a bit under a pixel every second. When the object is moving at this speed, it looks pretty choppy, because it only moves once every second.

Is there any way that I could blend the movement so that it moves at say 1/8th of a pixel every 1/8th of a second through the use of possibly anti-aliasing? Is there a way I could create a smoother transition between the two frames that makes it look like the object is consistently moving rather than moving a pixel every second?

I am currently using a float system for all of my positions and velocities, however I do not know how to render the image using floats. I am currently using `java.awt.Graphics drawImage`, which uses integers, rather than floats.

Comment: Are you able to Photoshop a screenshot what it would look like if it was moved .25 pixels? I assume you work on low resolution so pixels are that obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, so here's broad answer: Store object position and render it using floats instead of integers.

Comment: I am using floats to store the positions and velocities of all of the objects. I am just unsure as to how to render them in the float format. I am currently using graphics.drawImage(Image image, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer). How would I render an image using floats?

Comment: @CamH: See, that kind of details should have been in the question from the start. Do you have other ways of drawing using floats ?

Comment: @CamH Does this looks familiar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676909

Comment: Just looked up how to draw using floats, and found an answer, thankyou for your help! Here is the article I found useful for others interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676909/drawing-an-image-using-sub-pixel-level-accuracy-using-graphics2d